# How to make Model.clean work before saving?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm a beginner in Django and I'm trying to make a quiz app. I need to have a validation for admin panel so at least one answer was correct and at least one answer was wrong. I override a clean() method, it works incorrectly. For example - I make all answers incorrect - saving is okay, than I want to change it back - it raises an error 'There should be at least one correct answer').

My models:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models


class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='images/quiz/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quizzes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def clean(self):
        correct_answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=self).filter(is_correct=True).count()
        if correct_answers == 0:
            raise ValidationError('There should be at least one correct answer')
        elif self.answers.count() == correct_answers:
            raise ValidationError('There should be at least one wrong answer')


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

It seems like the clean method works before save method with the original data and doesn't check new data which I'm trying to save. I tried to override the save() method with self.clean() before it, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this using Admin then you should override validation on Admin form. See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin